# Reuse istream_iterator variable

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using two iterators to read from a text file into a `vector`:

```
std::ifstream input_file("~/blahblah.txt");
std::istream_iterator<float> start(input_file),end;
std::vector<float> testFrameFloat(start,end);
input_file.close();input_file.clear();
```

and then, I use the same `ifstream` to read another text file. Is it possible to reuse the same `istream_iterators` instead of creating new ones? I am getting compilation errors if I try to do so:

```
input_file.open("~/anothertext.txt");
start(input_file); //this is a compilation error
std::vector<float> readValues(start,end);
```

Comment: `start = input_file;`